# How can i replace image ? (JS)

Tags: javascript, image

How can i replace image? Tag  don't have id.

```
      <img src="URL_1"   />
```

I want replace **URL_1** to **URL_2**

Some solution?

Comment: Some research? You can find lots of results when searching _“how to select an element without an ID”_ and _“how to change the src of an img”_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the URL you can use

```
document.querySelector('img[src="URL_1"]').src = "URL_2";
```

If you don't know the URL and can use an id this would be it:

```
<img id="id" src="URL_1" />

document.getElementById("id").src = "URL_2";
```

Comment: Not working :(( https://big-01.app-ly.eu/upload/69c060f57633c00341cfb349b3eeae96db04fecb.png

Comment: i know IMG URL but a can't add element ID :/

Comment: Enclose the url in `""` in the selector

Comment: watch this -> https://big-01.app-ly.eu/upload/e0f7a0ad91f154307c00f876fdd3de54d506d16c.png whats wrong?

Comment: try this `document.querySelector('img[src="URL_1"]')`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that's the only image in the page you can use the [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) to reference the element, and edit its `src` property:

`document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'URL_2'`

The [Selectors API](https://flaviocopes.com/selectors-api/) is more appropriate as you can target the element with more details, using a CSS selector:

`document.querySelectorAll('img')[0].src = 'URL_2'`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add an `id` or a `class` maybe you can wrap your `img` tag with a `div` and use more specificity `div .myclass img`, last solution I see is if you know `URL_1` you can select this `img` tag by the selector: `img[src="URL_1"]`

Answer (score -1):

First of all, give an ID to your image

**Html code**

```
<img id="my_image" src="URL_1"/>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$("#my_image").attr("src","URL_2");
```

**Or without using Jquery**

```
document.getElementById("my_image").src="URL_2";
```

Comment: @KubaHon could you add a class?

Answer (score -1):

Give it an ID

```
<img id="img1" src="URL_1"   />
```

Then

```
document.getElementById('img1').setAttribute('src', 'URL_2');
```

Comment: i can't add ID :(